# Cloth Simulation is not being interactive

Tags: cloth-simulation

I tried to drag my cloth using hook. I couldn't make my cloth interact or drag. When I apply cloth simulation to the plane  and hook modifier to certain vertices and drag the process it doesnt work. The empty or hook just moves individually without dragging the cloth along with it.

This is my Blend file: 
 [image]

Comment: Hello, you've not shared the file but just the image, please share the link

Comment: Sure This is My blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=6rA0L1zr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/6rA0L1zr/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Blender struggles to calculate the result, but if for example you invert the *Group* then back to default it will recalculate correctly. But if you only use one empty you could simply parent the cloth the empty instead of using the *Hook* modifier.

[image]

Comment: Okay Let me try the inverse method because i have already tried the parenting method and it didnt work

Comment: It's just a way to refresh the simulation